# ps: get short command name and elapsed time

Tags: linux, debian, ps, output

I am on a Debian 8 System trying to determine the processes and their respective runtime of a certain user:

```
$ ps -u <user>
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26038 ?        00:00:00 php5-fpm
26052 ?        00:00:00 php5-fpm
26950 ?        00:00:00 php5-fpm
27344 ?        00:00:00 php5-fpm
28292 ?        00:00:00 php5-fpm
28691 ?        01:54:21 python3 /usr/lo
$ which ps  # ps is not aliased or so.
/bin/ps
```

Now I *additionally* want the elapsed time for the respective processes.
So I tried:

```
$ ps -o cmd=,etime= -u <user>
php-fpm: pool <user>         00:36
php-fpm: pool <user>         00:36
php-fpm: pool <user>         00:24
php-fpm: pool <user>         00:18
php-fpm: pool <user>         00:04
python3 /usr/local/bin/fixw    17:39:44
```

However I want to have the short process names `php-fpm` as in the first output, not the long names of the second one. I could not find any ways to so it, reading `ps`'s man page.
How do I get the CMD of output #1 with the elapsed time of output #2?

**Solution**
@StephenKitt's answer was the missing hint.
However, I needed to modify it slightly.
Strange output:

```
$ ps -o comm=,etime= -u <user>
,etime=
php5-fpm
php5-fpm
php5-fpm
php5-fpm
php5-fpm
ps
python3 /usr/lo
```

Separated options work:

```
$ ps -o comm= -o etime= -u <user>
php5-fpm              00:55
php5-fpm              00:27
php5-fpm              00:24
php5-fpm              00:13
php5-fpm              00:08
python3 /usr/lo    17:49:38
```

Comment: If you use the correct CLI from the man page (`ps -o comm,etime -u <user>) it works ;-)

Comment: Then I get unwanted headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the column name, the output you’re looking for is `comm` rather than `cmd`:

```
ps -o comm= -o etime= -u <user>
```

`cmd` is a non-standard alias for `args` and shows the command with all its arguments, including any modifications the process has made.

`comm` is the *process name* which on Linux by default is the first 15 bytes of the base name of the last file the process executed (or is the same name as its parent process if it didn't execute any file, or the task name for kernel tasks), and can be modified with the `PR_SET_NAME` `prctl()`.

Note that `etime` is the amount of time since the process was spawned, and a process can (and often does) run more than one command in their lifetime, so if you see `cmd 00:03`, that doesn't necessarily mean `cmd` has been running for 3 seconds, the process that is currently running `cmd` could very well have run some other command before.

```
$ sh -c 'sleep 3; exec ps -o comm= -o etime='
zsh                   13:48
ps                    00:03
```

The process running `ps` was previously running `sh` during which it spent most of its time waiting for another process running `sleep` (after having run `sh` for a very short time).

Comment: @Stéphane not at all, thanks! Your mention of `prctl` prompted me to re-read the `ps` manpage (from `procps-ng`) and it turns out it’s slightly inaccurate since it claims the `comm` entry *doesn’t* show name changes, but a quick test reveals it does. (I’ll send a patch...)